# How to translate style.fontSize = value for html5 documents?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code below, the script doesn't do what it does if you remove the doctype (ie. it does not increase the text size).
How to convert the fontSize affectation to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
        <style>
            #hello {
                font-family: "AvenirNextCondensed-Bold";
                font-size: 12pt;
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>

        <div id="hello">
            Hello
        </div>
        <script>
        document.getElementById("hello").style.fontSize = 50;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `'50px'` instead of `50`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the `!doctype`, you can change your js into this:

```
document.getElementById("hello").style.fontSize = "50px";
```

:)

Comment: You're right, being strict, one need to set the unit.

Comment: Don't worry, you're good enough. I made a fix to your english to avoid confusion. Your solution is the right answer. Thanks you save me time @Tyler.z.yang!